# Get the ontology classes by hierarchical levels

Tags: owl, owl-api

I wanna get ontology classes but not in a randomly way, I'm looking for a way to get them by their hierarchical levels: I mean showing for each level of the ontology its classes; is it possible, knowing that I'm using OWL API.

Comment: Simple Java programming with recursion starting from `owl:Thing` and getting all direct subclasses...if you're too lazy to implement it by yourself, you can you look the OWL API examples. It's already there. But I'd try it alone first. It's basic programming

Comment: I know, it must be a simple recursion program, what I'm looking for is how can I get each ontology level to search then within each level all subclasses: I mean if there is a function from OWL API which can return hierarchical levels or at least browse the ontology according to its depth not randomly . Thank you

Comment: There is no function to return levels. the number of levels has obviously to be determined by traversing the subclass hierarchy down

Answer (score 0):

```
OWLDataFactory df = OWLManager.getOWLDataFactory();
OWLReasoner reasoner = ...
NodeSet<OWLClass> subClasses = reasoner.getSubClasses(df.getOWLThing(), true);
```

`subClasses` will contain the set of direct subclasses of `owl:Thing` - i.e., the classes one level below `owl:Thing`. From there, you can apply the same call for each entity in the `NodeSet` to visit the class graph. You'll of course need an `OWLReasoner` implementation to create the `reasoner` object.